# How can i autopost to my Twitter account?

Tags: php, twitter, feed

I have a Twitter account. I have some data i receive from a third party. When new data arrives (these are football lineups) I want to post this to my Twitter. The data arrives approximately 60-30 minutes before matches start. 
I've tried using twitterfeed but it checks only every 30 minutes - and this can result in tweets with data for matches that already started.

How can i post my data automatically...and almost instantly upon reception?

-Rasmus

Comment: You can take a look on cronjobs.

Comment: Yes, that would be great. But does Twitter in their API have functionality to tweet without using their site or apps?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:
https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php

Great code for posting to twitter:

```
require_once('includes/TwitterAPIExchange.php');

$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "OWN",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "OWN",
    'consumer_key' => "OWN",
    'consumer_secret' => "OWN"
);

$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json';
$requestMethod = 'POST';

$postfields = array(
    'status' => 'Testing'
);

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
echo  $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
      ->setPostfields($postfields)
      ->performRequest();
```

Only thing i needed to change in the library was to add "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false" to the cURL made, as I did not get any return values or see any tweets.